# Regex replace string, but only if non-whitespace before the string

Tags: c#, regex

I have to replace `'- '` [dash][space] on empty string, but only if before `'-'` is character. For example

```
abcd- efg
abcd - efg 
// into 
abcdefg
abcd - efg
```

I tried regular expression like `'[^ ]- '` but this replace character before dash to.

Comment: What do you mean "only if before `-` is character"? Do you mean only if preceding character is not whitespace? What if `-` is at the beginning of the line?

Comment: Yes, if prescending character is not whitespace, if `-` is at the beginning dont change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookbehind..:

```
(?<=\w)-           // (?<=\w)[dash][space]
```

and replace with empty string

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5cw)-+&i=abcd-+efg%0d%0aabcd+-+efg+&r=)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
(?<=\w)-
```